# How to change rows into columns in SQL Server 2008 (multiple tables, joins etc)

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql, dynamic-columns

I need help with creating a report for a survey application. 
There are 5 main tables involved:

- Surveys (ID, ReportColumnName)
- Sections (ID, SectionName)
- Surveys_Sections(FK_Surveys, FK_Sections, Active)
- Sections_Surveys_ScoreValues (FK_Surveys, FK_Sections, FK_ScoreCategories, SectionScoreValue)
- ScoreCategories (ID, ScoreStart, ScoreEnd, CategoryName)

Every time a survey is created, a new `ReportColumnName` is generated that will need to be a column in the report. For each of these columns, and for each section (that is active in a survey), there is going to be a `SectionScoreValue`. This is linked further and checked whether it's inside an interval from `ScoreCategories`, and a resulting category (`CategoryName`) is shown for each survey and section.

I've been looking for days now on how to properly pivot these columns and show the needed values properly. By making an adaptation to some code got from a website, I thought this was going to work:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max), @Cols nvarchar(max)
select @Cols = 
stuff(
(
  select ', ' + quotename(dt)
  from 
  (
    select TOP 100 PERCENT Sv.ID, Sv.ReportColumnName as dt 
    from Surveys AS Sv
    ORDER BY Sv.ID
  ) X
  ORDER BY X.ID FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,''
)

SELECT @Cols

set @SQL = 
'SELECT Sv.ReportColumnName, SSSV.* 
FROM Surveys AS Sv 
INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys__ScoreValues AS SSSV
   ON SSSV.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
INNER JOIN Sections AS Sc
   ON Sc.ID = SSSV.FK_Sections_ID
INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys AS SS 
   ON SS.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
   AND SS.FK_Sections_ID = Sc.ID
INNER JOIN ScoreCategories AS ScoreC 
   ON ScoreC.ID = SSSV.FK_ScoreCategories_ID

PIVOT (max(SSSV.SectionScoreValue) FOR Sv.ReportColumnName IN (' + @Cols
+')) pvt'

execute (@sql)
```

The `@Cols` variable holds the columns I need (i.e. the surveys' names) and it displays them properly (and delimited by a comma). So this part is working fine.

My issue is with the next part that should have put (initially) the `SectionScoreValue` for each `SectionName` (on the first column), and each of the surveys (each one on a separate column).

These surveys columns are added dynamically upon creation of a new one, so they are never a constant number.

Each of these tables has also a `CreateDate` column that has a default to `GetDATE()`. The errors I'm getting are:

> The column 'CreateDate' was specified multiple times for 'pvt'.
>   The multi-part identifier "Sv.ReportColumnName" could not be bound.
>   The column prefix 'SSSV' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Please help in properly displaying my data. It should show something like:

```
Section Survey1 Survey2 Survey3 ......
s1        1.33    1.66    2.5
s2        0.00    3.33    4
s3        2.33    2       1.66
s4        0.66    2.5     3
```

The numbers can also be replaced with a value from ScoreCategoryName (like 'Good', 'Excellent' etc, according to the interval in which the number resides).

Thank you

**EDIT 1**: this is what `PRINT @SQL` yields:

```
SELECT Sv.ReportColumnName, SSSV.* 
FROM Surveys AS Sv 
INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys__ScoreValues AS SSSV
    ON SSSV.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
INNER JOIN Sections AS Sc
    ON Sc.ID = SSSV.FK_Sections_ID
INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys AS SS 
    ON SS.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
    AND SS.FK_Sections_ID = Sc.ID
INNER JOIN ScoreCategories AS ScoreC 
    ON ScoreC.ID = SSSV.FK_ScoreCategories_ID

PIVOT (max(SSSV.SectionScoreValue) FOR Sv.ReportColumnName 
IN ( [S1-1-2 -3], [S217], [al 3], [S37], [R4], [ult_nume_col])) pvt
```

**EDIT 2:** thanks to Giorgi I managed to get to a solution! Here's the **final code** that displays the columns exactly how I needed them:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max), @Cols nvarchar(max)
select @Cols = 
stuff(
(
    select ', ' + quotename(dt)
    from 
    (
        select TOP 100 PERCENT Sv.ID, Sv.ReportColumnName as dt 
        from Surveys AS Sv
        ORDER BY Sv.ID
    ) X
    ORDER BY X.ID FOR XML PATH('')



),1,1,''
)

SELECT @Cols

SET @SQL = ';
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT Sv.CreateDate, Sv.ReportColumnName, Sc.SectionName, SSSV.SectionScoreValue 
                FROM Surveys AS Sv 
                INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys__ScoreValues AS SSSV
                    ON SSSV.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
                INNER JOIN Sections AS Sc
                    ON Sc.ID = SSSV.FK_Sections_ID
                INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys AS SS 
                    ON SS.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
                    AND SS.FK_Sections_ID = Sc.ID
                INNER JOIN ScoreCategories AS ScoreC 
                    ON ScoreC.ID = SSSV.FK_ScoreCategories_ID
             )
    SELECT  SectionName , ' + @Cols + '
    FROM    cte PIVOT ( MAX(cte.SectionScoreValue) FOR cte.ReportColumnName IN (' + @Cols + ') ) pvt'

print @sql

execute (@sql)
```

Thanks for all the help guys, and for the "vote down" (if I could get to a result on my own I wouldn't have posted here).

Comment: I'd suggest writing this with hard coded columns first to make sure you get the logic right, then convert it.  Plus it would be easier to figure out the issue if you posted sample data for each table, along with the table structure.  You can also `print @sql` to see what the query syntax is and then debug from there.

Comment: Can you post an example value of your sql variable that is generating this error?

Comment: thanks for your replies. I've edited the OP with the value from Print @SQL;
There seems to be an issue in the PIVOT, with those dynamic column names, but I don't know how to fix them (since their number will vary all the time). Something similar to this seemed to be working where I tried to adapt the code from.

Comment: @XYZ Just guessing but have you tried changing `select ', ' + quotename(dt)` to `select distinct ', ' + quotename(dt)`?

Comment: Error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. 

When i try to add it to the order by clause, it doesn't work (probably because there's a FOR XML PATH in there).

Comment: @XYZ You'll have to alter the syntax, then to use `GROUP BY` instead of DISTINCT.  Without seeing some sample data it's extremely difficult to debug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always use table expressions when dialing with pivoting. Something like this:

```
SET @SQL = ';
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   SSSV.SectionScoreValue ,
                        Sv.ReportColumnName ,
                        Section
               FROM     Surveys AS Sv
                        INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys__ScoreValues AS SSSV ON SSSV.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID
                        INNER JOIN Sections AS Sc ON Sc.ID = SSSV.FK_Sections_ID
                        INNER JOIN Sections_Surveys AS SS ON SS.FK_Surveys_ID = Sv.ID AND SS.FK_Sections_ID = Sc.ID
                        INNER JOIN ScoreCategories AS ScoreC ON ScoreC.ID = SSSV.FK_ScoreCategories_ID
             )
    SELECT  Section , ' + @Cols + '
    FROM    cte PIVOT ( MAX(SSSV.SectionScoreValue) FOR Sv.ReportColumnName IN (' + @Cols + ') ) pvt'
```

Also you can look at my answer on similar question:

[SQL Pivot query based on "SUM of a column divided by SUM of another column"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494067/sql-pivot-query-based-on-sum-of-a-column-divided-by-sum-of-another-column/28494395#28494395)

Comment: Thanks for the help! After a few changes I got it working (and updated the OP).